# Why do many Operators execute external functions?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I've been coding with Blender for about a year and I have noticed a lot of developers call an external function from the execute function of an Operator. Below is the Simple Operator template that ships with Blender. In this case, why is the code in `main` not in the Operator's `execute` method? There aren't any in this example, but wouldn't it be easier to reference Operator properties from coding within the Operator? Thank you.

```py
import bpy


def main(context):
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        print(ob)


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text=SimpleOperator.bl_label)


# Register and add to the "object" menu (required to also use F3 search "Simple Object Operator" for quick access).
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the Blender Developer [Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Interface/Operators) under **Good Practice**:

> Abusing operator callbacks as functions: Often, operator exec() and
> invoke() callbacks contain a bunch of logic at mixed levels of
> abstraction. For example, iterators, complex condition checking,
> bit-flag operations, calls to other functions, ... This indicates that
> the operators deal with business logic themselves, rather than letting
> the model handle it -- a violation of the Model, View, Controller
> design that has consequences. Operators should just use high-level API
> functions of well defined modules. These should be unit tested and may
> be used by other parts of Blender, like the Python API. The operator
> then just puts a few pieces together to perform an action through the
> UI.

Meaning essentially the Operator class itself should (in an ideal world) only contain a bunch of properties related to the Operator (that a user would see in a popup for instance) and then an execute that contains a call to one function that takes the context and then returns `{"FINISHED"}`.

Since `bpy.types.Operator` is part of the Controller component of the MVC pattern, while `bpy.types.Vert` or `Object` or `Image` are part of the Model component, you want to restrict the mixing of the two unnecessarily.

A good example of why this is useful is if you were trying to write [unittests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) you can very easily write tests like:

```
import bpy
from bpy import data

# say this is the function that sits outside of your operator class
# that you want to test

def move_on_x_by_one(obj):
    obj.x += 1.0

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       self.data = bpy.data
       self.objs = [
            self.data.objects.new('test_obj',self.data.meshes.new('test_mesh'))
            for i in range(5)
       ] 

    def test_upper(self):
        obj = self.objs[0]
        first_loc = obj.location.x
        move_on_x_by_one(obj)
        # find out if this function did what it's supposed to
        self.assertEqual(obj.location.x, first_loc + 1.0)
```

This is an incredibly simple example, but if you have an operator that is dependent on 50 different smaller functions to do it's thing, you write unittests for each one, and then have them run every time you save your file. Then if you ever find a failure on this specific function while running tests you know exactly what part of your operator is messing up.

If you tried to run a unittest with just a call to `bpy.ops.my_op_to_test()` and it has 200 lines of for loops, math, if/else statements and other heavy-duty code all bundled under the `Operator.execute()` method and all your unittest results say is `FAILED: bpy.ops.my_op_to_test() did not return {"FINISHED"}` you have essentially no idea where to look.

If you want to see an example of this in practice, look at `{your_blender_source_folder}/3.x/scripts/addons/object_cell_fracture/`. The whole addon is ~1000 lines of code and this is what the execute method looks like under the CellFracture operator:

```
def execute(self, context):
    keywords = self.as_keywords()  # ignore=("blah",)

    main(context, **keywords)

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Hope this helps, now if you'll excuse me I need to go refactor my addons.